# Does the orbit map induce an isomorphism (or a monomorphism) in Alexander -Spanier cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, transformation-groups

Let $G$ be a compact and totally disconnected group acting on a paracompact space $X$.

> Does the orbit map $X \rightarrow X/G$ induce an isomorphism (or a monomorphism) in Alexander-Spanier cohomology with closed support?

Answer (score 2):

The following is a related result of Bredon et al and Lowen. You may find more in [this book](http://www.indiana.edu/%7Ejfdavis/seminar/Bredon,Introduction_to_Compact_Transformation_Groups.pdf) by Bredon.

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be  a  totally  disconnected compact group that acts on a locally  compact Hausdorff space $X$, and let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Then the orbit projection $X\rightarrow X/G$ induces an isomorphism
> $$H_c^{*}(X/G;k)\cong \text{Fix}(G;H_c^{*}(X;k)).$$

Also, take a look at [this paper](http://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20005a7b_1319.pdf) by Satea Deo.

Comment: It is true for locally compact spaces. I dont know that it is true for paracompact spaces. I read Deo's article